# Y event.context.params.id is showing undefine in nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs3

```
 
  import sql from "mssql";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const db = {
    ...useRuntimeConfig().db,
    database: event.context.params?.db_name,
  };
  const table = "questions";
  const catable = "Categories";

  await sql.connect(db);
    let result;
    if (event.node.req.method === "GET") {
   // const id = 1;
    const id = event.context.route.params.id;
    // console.log(event);
    // console.log(event.context.params);

    result = await sql.query(
      `SELECT Category, Description,Icon, Title,ID FROM ${catable} 
      JOIN ${table} ON ${catable}.CategoryId = ${table}.CategoryId WHERE ${catable}.CategoryId=${id}`
    );
  }
});
```

I want to retrieve dynamic route id it to capture so that i can fetch data according to the id
what shoul i do

Comment: Is your file named correctly, like `server/api/db/[id].js`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @learntheropes my file named is server/routes/db/[db_name]/[id].ts

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the server with the syntax that is used on the client routes (`/pages` folder).

On the server, you get the params from the event using the available H3 Requests Helpers.

In this case the helper to use is `getRouterParams` (for all the params) or `getRouterParam` (for a named param):

In a server enpoint named `server/routes/db/[db_name]/[id].ts` as you shared in the comment, the basic function is:

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  return {
    params: getRouterParams(event),
    id: getRouterParam(event,'id'),
    db_name: getRouterParam(event,'db_name')
  }
});
```

If you fetch it from the client with `await $fetch('/routes/db/foo/123'`, you will get:

```json
{
  "params": {
    "db_name": "foo",
    "id": "123"
  },
  "db": "foo",
  "id": "123"
}
```

You can adapt it to interact with your sql.

Documentation for [Server Utilities](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-utilities)
Documentation for [`getRouterParam` function](https://www.jsdocs.io/package/h3#getRouterParam)

See a minimal working replication [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-gvg8ac?file=server%2Fapi%2Fdb%2F%5Bdb_name%5D%2F%5Bid%5D.js)